# Redirect error when trying to request a url with requests/urllib only in python

Tags: python, django, redirect, curl, urllib

im trying to post data to a url in my server ... but im stuck in sending any request to that url  (any url on that server ) here is one for example

```
http://apimy.in/page/test
```

the website is written in python3.4/django1.9

i can send request with `curl` in `php` without any problem

but any request with python will result on some kind of redirect error

at first i've tried `requests` lib

i got this error

```
TooManyRedirects at /api/sender
Exceeded 30 redirects.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/sender
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: TooManyRedirects
Exception Value:

Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

i thought maybe something wrong with `requests` so i tried `urllib`

```
request_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"DATA": 'aaa'}).encode()
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://apimy.in/page/test" , data=request_data)



HTTPError at /api/sender
HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/sender
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: HTTPError
Exception Value:    
HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
Exception Location: c:\Python344\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_302, line 675
```

im using mod_wsgi and apache to serve the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module did you try to tell the requests module to ignore redirects?

```
import requests
response = requests.get('your_url_here', allow_redirects=False)
```

Maybe this work.
If this doesn't work, you can also try to change your `user-agent` in case your server is configured to drop `script-requests` for security reasons.

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'some_user_agent'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: thanx ,  by disabling redirect if got `The document has moved` error ...but by setting user agen i got it working thanx